# What kind of tool can be use to produce this graph?

Tags: graphics, matplotlib

I am new at graphing tools for big data analysis. Though the following is not from big data, I was wondering what kind of tools are used to create this kind of complex graph:

http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/mem_lat3.pdf

Associated with the paper http://www.bitmover.com/lmbench/lmbench-usenix.pdf

Comment: It doesn't look that complex.  It's just a 3D plot with perspective, and colouring based on height.  Surely you can do it in Excel or gnuplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is made in [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) (particulary [groff](http://www.gnu.org/software/groff/) project), according to metadata in the chart's PDF, it's saved to PDF from Photoshop (so this lead ends here). Anyway, the [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) or [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) ([see gallery](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/3D%20graphs/)) are capable of drawing charts like this..

Answer (score 2):

Looks a little bit like gnuplot, but it can be perfectly done by matplotlib. An example can be found at [this page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I never noticed this question before. Larry borrowed that graphic from me and it was created with Excel.

I was considering adding code to lmbench to create that plot automatically and Thorsten's suggestion of mplot3d sounds like a good place to start.